# TexShop Find All missing

Tags: editors, texshop, find, search

Earlier versions of TexShop had a "Find All" button in the find panel (along with "Replace All", "Find Next", etc), which popped up a list of all the instances of the search string, with line numbers.  How do I enable / get back this button/option in the newest version of TexShop?  Find All is an essential operation, and despite attempts to modify my workflow, the absence of the feature is a persistent problem---not just an inconvenience but it actually makes complex find operations in large projects infeasible in TexShop.  I can't imagine the rationale for eliminating this basic feature, so I hope it is just buried somewhere for activation.  Thanks.

Comment: What version are you using? TeXShop3.95 does have `Replace All` and Find Next as `Next`. Use Command F to pop up the `Find` panel. Not sure about `Find All` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXShop has two Find panels, an Apple one, which is quite simple (and doesn't have a Find All button) and and OgreKit one, which has many more functions, including regular expression matching, and also has a Find All button.  The simple find panel looks like this:

[image: Apple Search Panel]

The OgreKit panel looks like this:

[image: OgreKit Search Panel]

You can change which panel is used in the TeXShop preferences (restart of TeXShop required to show the change).

There's also the possibility of using the Apple Find bar, which is even more limited:

[image: Apple Find Bar]