# Texshop find all missing in ogrekit panel

Tags: texshop

I have a new version of Tex Shop and surprisingly the "Find all" is missing in the Ogrekit panel (see the picture below. It is in french but I guess you can see what is happening). Does someone has an idea how to make it come back? Note that I have "replace all" and "replace and find".

The only options I see are changing the ogrekit to the standard apple find bar and go back, but it does not change anything. Some earlier question was related [TexShop Find All missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407686/texshop-find-all-missing)
but the answer only explains the difference between the different search panels.

[image]

Comment: This is from the release notes »TeXShop 4.50 contains an OgreKit with the fatal "Find All" bug. But in Version 4.51 of TeXShop, I removed the "Find All" button from the OgreKit Panel, so users should be unable to create the error.

There is no chance that I'll find time to fix OgreKit, but I prefer to leave it in TeXShop in its imperfect state for users who need regular expressions. (…) These bugs won't be fixed unless some volunteer is willing to take over the project, which would be wonderful.«

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is definitely sad that this "imperfect state" stays like this. I might then have to switch to another program if this really won't be fixed.

Comment: Same with me. I made the switch to TeXstudio for now.

Comment: Richard Koch just wrote to me: »The good news is that the author of OgreKit sent a fixed version to me yesterday. I expect to release TeXShop 4.53 with this fixed version later this morning.«

Comment: Thanks. I just installed the new version and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of OgreKit provided a fixed version yesterday. TeXShop 4.53 will be released later this morning with this fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a very good news. It works very well.